# Italian past participle ending -uto

Tags: morphology, latin, romance-languages, italian, participles

Why, in the paradigm for Italian past participles ending in `-ere`, does the regular past participle end in `-uto`? Whence the vowel, when the other two paradigms have `-ato` and `-ito`?

Comment: Can't help upvoting it! :D

Comment: This always bothered me about the Italian paradigm. I have suspicions based on how all the Latin first and fourth conjugation verbs have perfects ending in `-atus` and `-itus`, but the second conjugation verbs do not, but I'm hoping that someone can resolve this once and for all.

Comment: I'll try to answer this later. :)

Comment: Hopefully we can get Italian.SE started at some point...

Comment: Yes, although I think this is more interesting for a Linguistics audience. I mean, it's certainly good for the language learners too, but I think this historical part is more for us. :)

Comment: I guess that whatever the answer is, it also accounts for French pp's in -u (perdu, fondu). I wonder if it is connected with Latin perfects in -ui, even though the '-u-' (from '-ev-') doesn't occur in the Supine in Latin.

Comment: @Alenanno You're keeping me in suspense!

Comment: @jogloran I'm writing it, but it takes time because I'm looking for many references.

Comment: @Alenanno: Much appreciated.

Comment: @Alenanno: I was wondering if this was still on your radar. I understand if you've had too much on your plate!

Comment: @jogloran Yes sorry! I did write something, but it's still incomplete for now.

Comment: @Alenanno: Again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is briefly discussed in *The Romance Languages*, on pages 296-7 (in the chapter on Italian by Nigel Vincent). The author explains the origins of some irregular preterits and past participles occurring with second-conjugation verbs. According to him, a number of these verbs derive their irregular preterit base from the Latin perfect marker -U-, which produced gemination of a preceding consonant (e.g. VOLUI > *volli*, 'I wanted').He notes that these are also the verbs with participles in -*u*-: *avuto*, *conosciuto*, *voluto*, etc., and explains thus:

Although this participial -*u*- is etymologically from a different source,   namely verbs in -UO such as BATTUO 'I beat', it extended its range considerably in late Latin...suggesting that it had been morphologically reanalysed as being the same element as perfective -U-.... Finally, in this connection, we may note the form [of the verb *vivere*] *vissuto* 'lived' < *VIXUTUM, which represents the extension of the -UTUM suffix to the already sigmatic Latin perfect from VIXI. The original Latin participle VICTUM survives instead in the word *vitto* 'food'.

Of course, there remains a large number (he estimates about 200) of irregular second-conjugation participles, and he notes that in other areas of Italy, i.e. the South, where the preterit is still used daily, corresponding preterit and participial forms in local languages have undergone analogical leveling and are more regular. I'm aware that in northern Italy where, conversely, the preterit is extinct in many local languages (and where even speakers of Standard Italian simply don't use it), those languages have likewise simplified second-conjugation participles by analogical extension of the -*u* (widely phonetically realized as [y]).

Comment: I look forward to seeing @Alenanno's explanation, but for the time being, accepted, and welcome!